# Quick question about solutions to a question concerning quotient ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]
I have a quick question about the allowed function use to show isomorphism between quotient rings.   The question assumes the following exercise:

Let $R=\{a+bi|a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and $J=\{a+bi| 5|a, 5|b\}.$ Show that $J$ is not a maximal ideal in $R$ (Hint: Consider the principal ideal $K=\{a+bi\}$ in $R$)

The question asks:
If $R$ and $J$ are as in Exercise 1, show that $R/J \cong \mathbb{Z_{5}}$

I know that we can define $\psi: R\rightarrow \mathbb{Z_{5}}$ by $\psi(a+bi)=[a-2b]_{5}$, but can I use the function $\psi(a+bi)=[a+2b]_{5}$ instead?

Note:  it is question 24 in the attached picture which assumes notations from exercises 21(a) and 22.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, you cannot show both statements “$J$ is not a maximal ideal” and “$R/J\cong\mathbb{Z}_5$”, because they contradict each other.

Comment: @egreg I fixed the question.  I think the way I typed it might caused a bit of a misunderstanding.  It question assumes the first statement.  I am not sure if $[a+2b]_{5}$ would make the solution not work instead of  $[a-2b]_{5}$.

Comment: Again, if $J$ is as in the stated exercise, then $R/J$ *cannot* be isomorphic to a field, but $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field.

Comment: @egreg I have fixed the question with attached screenshot of where the exercises came from and also fixed the typing of the post.  My profuse apologies for the confusions.

Comment: We have many prior questions showing how to prove such isomorphisms, e.g. see the linked dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text doesn't match the screenshot. You're required to prove that if $K=(2+i)$, then $R/K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

One way is to consider the map $\psi\colon R\to\mathbb{Z}_5$ defined by $\psi(a+bi)=[a-2b]_5$.

Is this a ring homomorphism? One could check this via the definition, but there's a better way. We can consider $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}_5$ defined by $\varphi(x)=[-2]_5$.

Now we can see that the kernel of this homomorphism contains the ideal $I$ generated by $x^2+1$, because $\varphi(x^2+1)=[-2]_5^2+[1]_5=[0]_5$. Hence this homomorphism induces a ring homomorphism $\psi\mathbb{Z}/I\to\mathbb{Z}_5$ and $\psi(x+I)=[-2]_5$. Now we can “canonically” identify $R$ with $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ and we're done, because
$$
\psi(a+bi)=\psi(a)+\psi(b)\psi(i)=[a]_5+[b]_5[-2]_5=[a-2b]_5
$$

Can you do the same by mapping $x$ to $[2]_5$? Yes, why not? Repeat the argument and you're done.

Or consider that conjugation is an automorphism of $R$ and if $\psi'(a+bi)=[a+2b]_5$, then
$$
\psi'(a+bi)=\psi(\overline{a+bi})
$$
so $\psi'=\psi\circ j$, where $j$ is conjugation.

Comment: sorry I checked and fixed the typing to align with the screenshot.  THe solution from the text reads as follows:

"As in Exercise 22 define $\psi:R\rightarrow \mathbb{Z_{5}}$ by $\psi(a+bi)=[a-bi]_{5}$.  The work done there already implies that $\psi$ is a surjective homomorphism.  If $a+bi$ is in the kernel then $[a-bi]_{5}=[0]_{5}$, so that $a=2b+bq$ for some $q\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Therefore $a+bi=(2+i)b+5q=(2+i)\cdot(b+(2-i)q)$ lies in the ideal $(2+i)$.  Consequently the kernel is $(2+i)$ and the first isomorphism theorem can be applied."

What I like to know is.....

Comment: #egreg ...do I really need a conjugation map.  I often see conjugation map used when it involves complex numbers or proving things involving binomial theorem identities.

Comment: @SethMai It's a basic tool for complex numbers: why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: I know complex analysis, but when i see it used, there seems to be no rhyme or reasons for its use.  All i found in the textbook literature is that conjugation map has to do with complexification of a real vector spaces like in Berger's book:

https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Geometry_I/5W6cnfQegYcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=complexification+of+vector+spaces,+marcel+berger&pg=PA145&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @SethMai Conjugation is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ and it induces an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. What's the problem? Don't look too far: this is not “complex analysis”, but basic algebra.

Comment: ah okay okay.  Thank you for the explanation.  How can I miss this little detail.  Sometimes, when I do math, all the little things just don't come to the forefront readily.